# Cannot find `lcrypto` or `lssl` when building with Cargo

Tags: gcc, rust, rust-cargo

Rust and Cargo from 30/12/2014. GCC 4.8.3.

I got the following message on `cargo run` inside a project directory.

```
error: linking with `gcc` failed: exit code: 1
note: gcc '-Wl,--enable-long-section-names' '-fno-use-linker-plugin' '-Wl,--nxcompat' '-static-libgcc' '-m64' '-L' 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Rust\bin\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib' '-o' 'D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target\rust-web-iron.exe' 'D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target\rust-web-iron.o' '-Wl,--gc-sections' 'D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target\deps\libiron-9458c3a7430cd345.rlib' 'D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target\deps\libmodifier-f18d612d13fb7b64.rlib' 'D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target\deps\libplugin-c932a4ffd97a9fec.rlib' 'D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target\deps\libphantom-3c95ed32bb19cc57.rlib' 'D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target\deps\libhyper-37211ade1c8dfef3.rlib' 'D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target\deps\libmucell-dcebaca45047164d.rlib' 'D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target\deps\libmime-15d27ce21969eec5.rlib' 'D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target\deps\libtypemap-c4ec45abe5f40a37.rlib' 'D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target\deps\libunsafe-any-ef1867dfe1b38a9e.rlib' 'D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target\deps\liblog-25f1bf92e34cdaf5.rlib' 'D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target\deps\libregex-2b8b3341ed7ceeb7.rlib' 'D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target\deps\liberror-14128451581aeed2.rlib' 'D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target\deps\libtypeable-680493e87963e405.rlib' 'D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target\deps\libcookie-e7b4e699158b9dc4.rlib' 'D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target\deps\libtime-82dafc95a42caa7e.rlib' 'D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target\deps\liburl-e9f12437efec5264.rlib' 'D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target\deps\libopenssl-79e6c3ab8827c788.rlib' 'D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target\deps\librustc-serialize-bd3e38505da47309.rlib' 'D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target\deps\libopenssl-sys-c071ba4e5034c35b.rlib' 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Rust\bin\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libserialize-4e7c5e5c.rlib' 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Rust\bin\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\liblog-4e7c5e5c.rlib' 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Rust\bin\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libregex-4e7c5e5c.rlib' 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Rust\bin\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libstd-4e7c5e5c.rlib' 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Rust\bin\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libcollections-4e7c5e5c.rlib' 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Rust\bin\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\liballoc-4e7c5e5c.rlib' 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Rust\bin\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\liblibc-4e7c5e5c.rlib' 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Rust\bin\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\librand-4e7c5e5c.rlib' 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Rust\bin\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libunicode-4e7c5e5c.rlib' 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Rust\bin\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libcore-4e7c5e5c.rlib' '-L' 'D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target' '-L' 'D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target\deps' '-L' 'D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target\build\time-82dafc95a42caa7e\out' '-L' 'D:\__start\rust-web-iron\.rust' '-L' 'D:\__start\rust-web-iron' '-Wl,--whole-archive' '-Wl,-Bstatic' '-Wl,--no-whole-archive' '-Wl,-Bdynamic' '-lcrypto' '-lssl' '-lgdi32' '-lwsock32' '-lws2_32' '-lcompiler-rt'
note: ld: cannot find -lcrypto
ld: cannot find -lssl

error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `rust-web-iron`.

Caused by:
  Process didn't exit successfully: `rustc D:\__start\rust-web-iron\src\main.rs --crate-name rust-web-iron --crate-type bin -g --out-dir D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target --emit=dep-info,link -L D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target -L D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target\deps --extern iron=D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target\deps/libiron-9458c3a7430cd345.rlib -L D:\__start\rust-web-iron\target\build\time-82dafc95a42caa7e\out` (status=101)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using crates that depend on [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) and on [libcrypto](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Libcrypto_API). You must download, compile and install OpenSSL. Since you are using Windows, you should use [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) or [MSYS2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/) to build OpenSSL. MSYS2 has a package for OpenSSL, so it should be relatively easy to install.